# lowercase first n characters

Tags: python, lowercase

I'm trying to lowercase the first n characters in a string.

For example, say I want to lowercase the first 4 characters in this string:

```
String1 = 'HELPISNEEDED'
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
String1 = 'helpISNEEDED'
```

I thought I could use this:

```
String1 = String1[4].lower() + String1[5:]
```

but this gives me this output:

```
String1 = 'iSNEEDED'
```

Any idea on how I'm doing this wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You selected just *one character*. Use a slice for both parts:

```
String1 = String1[:4].lower() + String1[4:]
```

Note that the second object starts slicing at `4`, not `5`; you want to skip `'HELP'`, not `'HELPI'`:

```
>>> String1 = 'HELPISNEEDED'
>>> String1[:4].lower() + String1[4:]
'helpISNEEDED'
```

Remember: the start index is inclusive, the end index is exclusive; `:4` selects indices 0, 1, 2, and 3, while `4:` selects indices 4 and onwards.

Comment: The indices were my problem. Thank you for clearing that up :)

Answer (score 4):

You were only referencing a single character from `String1`, rather do it with list slicing:

```
String1.replace(String[:4],String1[:4].lower())
```

Comment: This still produces a new string object. It is no better than using concatenation. In fact, it is *worse*, as you ask Python to do more work.

Answer (score 2):

`[4]` takes fifth character, to take first four, you need, similarly to `[5:]` (last five), write `[:4]`.

Comment: Take the fifth instead of forth, it is zero indexed

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. Check your code. It should be :

```
String1=String1[:4].lower() + String1[4:]
```

Not only you forgot this --> [:4] . Also you wrote 's' inplace of String1