# Python How to lower n first character

Tags: python

```py
a = "HELLOGUYS"
def lowern(string,n) :
    for k in string[:n] :
         k.lower()
    return string
print(lowern(a,4))
```

It remained "HELLOGUYS".

Comment: What did you find out when you looked up the documentation for the `lower()` method?

Comment: [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) does not modify the string itself but returns a new copy since [strings are immutable.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str:~:text=strings%20are%20immutable%20sequences%20of%20unicode%20code%20points.%20string%20literals%20are%20written%20in%20a%20variety%20of%20ways%3A)

Comment: Related [lowercase first n characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34680657/15497888)

Answer (score 5):

[`str.lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) is **not** an in place method (strings are immutable). It returns the result, so you have to assign it back.

Also looping though every character is not efficient, use slicing instead:

```py
a = "HELLOGUYS"
a = a[:4].lower()+a[4:]
print(a)
```

As a function:

```py
def lowern(string, n) :
    return string[:n].lower()+string[n:]
```

output:

```
>>> lowern('HELLOGUYS', 4)
'hellOGUYS'
```

Answer (score 2):

When you loop over a string (or an iterable in general), you're not getting a direct control over it, instead they are copied values. Even more, with `k.lower()` you're not lowering `k`. This will return a new lowered character to you rather than changing `k`.

To do what you're intending to do, you'll need to re-assign things to `string` or return a new value.

Also, you don't need to iterate, you can lower the full string with `lower` not only a character.

```py
def lowern(string, n):
    return string[:n].lower() + string[n:]
```

Comment: I'd say rasing that exception is against the spirit of Python.

Comment: I would agree that it will happen by itself. However, if you think we should be returning an answer regardless, then I disagree. You should alert the dev when they have a mistake. I'm assuming this is a dev not a user, otherwise I would agree 100%.

Comment: What do you mean with "it will happen by itself"?

Comment: If we remove that `if` statement, then an exception would happen if n is out of bound.

Comment: [No it won't](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PyU1TSEnvzy1KE@juKQoMy9dRyFP04pLAQiKUktKi/IUIMLRVnmxemCFGpoK2jDBPKtYLq4CILNEA2qIulu@f5JjkbqOgpmZmabm//8A). And that's precisely why I think it's against the spirit of Python. Because Python itself does *not* do what you're doing.

Comment: That's true, my bad! Thanks for the catch.